# Multiply values in each column by second cell in each column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, multiplication

I have a sheet that contains: in row 1: date when containers has been checked
in row 2: average kg per bad in the particular day
row 3 below: number of bags picked up per each container.
My test table has range of A1:D8

I a trying to replicate this table from "Sheet1" to "Sheet2" and at the same time calculate how many kg has each container in a particular day multiplied by number of bags of each container.
I am able to calculate the cells with one fixed value. However, I am struggling how to multiply each column from row 3 below by the value in row 2.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim myVal As Range

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set rng = ws2.Range("A3:D8")

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:D8").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A8:D3")

For Each myVal In rng
myVal = myVal.Value * ws1.Range("A1")
Next myVal

End Sub
```

Comment: Suggest to edit some data to clarify by a *concrete example* what you actually want to calculate; - btw   is `.Range("A8:D3")` your destination range and not `.Range("A3:D8")`? Further hint: why do you set range objects `ws1` and `ws2` to memory if you don't use them?

Comment: you say `multiply each column from row 3 below by the value in row 2.` but why `myVal.Value * ws1.Range("A1")`. can you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be simple if you can pass thru the formula stage:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim myVal As Range

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set rng = ws2.Range("A3:D8")

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:D8").Copy Destination:=rng
rng.FormulaR1C1="='Sheet1'!R[0]C[0] * 'Sheet1'!R2C[0]"

For Each myVal In rng
    myVal.Formula = myVal.Value
Next myVal

End Sub
```

Furthermore, if you do not need to copy the formatting everytime, the `.Copy` statement can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, this is probably what you need:

in the following code, instead of iterating through each cell, I will create a matrix to perform the multiplication of 2 matrices, then use the MMULT function to return the result(see my image)

**Note:** This approach may not be very effective, it's just a temporary thought.

```
Sub Test()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim Rng As Range: Set Rng = ws2.Range("A3:D8")
Dim Header:   Header = ws1.[a2:d2].Value2
M_size = Rng.Columns.Count

ws1.Range("A3:D8").Copy Destination:=Rng

   Dim matrix() As Integer 
   ReDim matrix(M_size - 1, M_size - 1) As Integer:k = 1 'initialize matrix element=0

   For i = 1 To M_size
        matrix(i - 1, i - 1) = Header(1, k): k = k + 1   'change diagonal values
   Next i
   Rng = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(Rng, matrix)'multiply 2 matrices
End Sub
```

.

[image]

Hope it helps!